# absolute rotated div need to take space and not overflow from his parent (so childs decide the dimension of parent container)

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow

### image of the problem

the white background isn't showing when using absolute child

[image]

---

### the problem

the problem is that the white background of the parent isn't visible.

so maybe the `.canvas` width is set to 0.

yeah, I can add a hard-coded width, but I want that it to auto-size based on the content.

> the line is not placed relative so isn't in the document flow and this make it not be used as width.
>
> how can I solve this issue?

#### the html code

```css
.canvas {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  /* where is it?? */
}

.canvas .line {
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  height: 0.25rem;
}

.canvas .line:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<body style="background: grey;">

  <!-- generated by javascript -->

  <div class="canvas">
    <div class="line" style="width: 0px; transform: translate(0px, 0px) rotate(0deg);"></div>

    <div class="line" style="width: 22.3607px; transform: translate(10px, 20px) rotate(63.4349deg);"></div>

    <div class="line" style="width: 22.3607px; transform: translate(20px, 40px) rotate(63.4349deg);"></div>

    <div class="line" style="width: 22.3607px; transform: translate(30px, 60px) rotate(63.4349deg);"></div>

    <div class="line" style="width: 22.3607px; transform: translate(40px, 80px) rotate(63.4349deg);"></div>

    <div class="line" style="width: 22.3607px; transform: translate(50px, 100px) rotate(63.4349deg);"></div>

    <div class="line" style="width: 22.3607px; transform: translate(60px, 120px) rotate(63.4349deg);"></div>

    <div class="line" style="width: 22.3607px; transform: translate(70px, 140px) rotate(63.4349deg);"></div>

  </div>

</body>
```

## what does the code before do?

I have some divs with a parent div `relative` and some childs `absolute`

the child won't have any content/text inside

(the style of the div is parsed from javascript but isn't important to the code js, I will add you the result HTML).

the styles are width, translateX, translateY, rotate().

---

#### what do I need?

the final result needs to be like this:
[image]

---

## what I tried.

###### manually way (but I don't like to do like this)

if I set a width then it works

```html
<div class="canvas" style="width:100px; height:165px;">
```

Is it possible to automatically set the width from the first point to the last?

---

###### without `absolute` in lines (not working)

a possible solution, that is not adding `position:absolute;` to the lines

> but is very important for this case
>
> - there is a gap between every line.
>
> > this is happening because in CSS now also the height will be considered
> >
> > if you look closely, the gap is equal to the height of the previous line
>
> - now the white background is shown, but since the elements are rotated, this means that it will take up more space than it should be
>
> > let's say we have a div of the length of 1.4rem,
> >
> >  but when rotated the space occupied can be less or more
> >
> > > let's say we have a 1.4rem width and 45deg
> > >
> > >  is equal to 1rem of width and also height
> > >
> > > [image]
> >
> > as you see in the photo before, there is a square and we find the diagonal of it with the pitagora formula
> >
> > but not in all cases it will be a square, but can be a rectangle
> >
> > > so if is 25deg
> > >
> > > - the width it will be less than the width,
> > > - but the height is will be like the double of the width of the line

is very difficult and I am wondering how I can browser automatically do this calculation for me.

[image]

> this is the bug without `absolute`

---

so if you can I want to use `absolute` for accurate results, but without that bugs mentioned before.

Comment: Maybe it's a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What does this thing is supposed to do?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski display from a array of X and Y position the lines like we so it canvas. so css solution alternative to canvas. something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvVmO.png but in css

Comment: So you probably want to set the constant size of the parent component and calculate the position of each element relative to parent coordinates.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski then it will be very inefficient if I do in javascript. is there any formula for doing it efficiently. or css only way?

Comment: Pages usually run thousand of operations per second in JavaScript and it's not inefficient.

Comment: You could also use svg

Comment: ok I will try to see, I think I will try with css/js, because I don't know svgs. and do a `Math.max()` and set the value to the width

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73819800/find-maximum-number-in-array-of-objects for this problem of width. thanks for answering there