# find maximum number in array of objects?

Tags: javascript

how I can find the bigger and smaller number in the most efficient way in javascript (or the most easiest way)

something like this:

```js
function findMaxFromArray() {
  // logic
  return { x: ..., y: ... }
}
```

> I tried `Math.max(array.x)` and is not working

here the array:

```js
let array = [{
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0
  },
  {
    "x": 3.6417243968365076,
    "y": 10
  },
  {
    "x": 9.34437089784549,
    "y": 20
  },
  {
    "x": 0.7464057532722523,
    "y": 30
  },
  {
    "x": 10.254345841653576,
    "y": 40
  },
  {
    "x": 40.665266471734526,
    "y": 50
  },
  {
    "x": 13.605184580988041,
    "y": 60
  },
  {
    "x": 56.1970151503722,
    "y": 70
  },
  {
    "x": 46.30684270171864,
    "y": 80
  },
  {
    "x": 86.97417514998948,
    "y": 90
  },
  {
    "x": 19.086639005143002,
    "y": 100
  },
  {
    "x": 74.53073691009028,
    "y": 110
  },
  {
    "x": 80.51273650018987,
    "y": 120
  },
  {
    "x": 125.67651066602721,
    "y": 130
  },
  {
    "x": 94.92603682139705,
    "y": 140
  },
  {
    "x": 81.41258620429245,
    "y": 150
  },
  {
    "x": 128.79236053348222,
    "y": 160
  },
  {
    "x": 101.73294154449238,
    "y": 170
  },
  {
    "x": 176.92343490767377,
    "y": 180
  },
  {
    "x": 148.01122343809243,
    "y": 190
  },
  {
    "x": 13.666705559256798,
    "y": 200
  },
  {
    "x": 190.95447678085023,
    "y": 210
  },
  {
    "x": 186.02329838354444,
    "y": 220
  },
  {
    "x": 207.04643642736238,
    "y": 230
  },
  {
    "x": 75.3481702154557,
    "y": 240
  },
  {
    "x": 49.14228670472814,
    "y": 250
  },
  {
    "x": 203.65260758421869,
    "y": 260
  },
  {
    "x": 69.53501551989147,
    "y": 270
  },
  {
    "x": 269.52487694376975,
    "y": 280
  },
  {
    "x": 184.31351948105274,
    "y": 290
  },
  {
    "x": 19.72787138830958,
    "y": 300
  }
]
```

result output:

basically, we give an array of objects with `x`, `y` as a parameter to a function.

and the function should return the maximum x and maximum y

(for now, I don't need to calculate the minimum since is always 0, but it will help as well as a solution in that topic too)

```js
// output sample
return { 
  x: 269.52487694376975, 
  y: 300 
}

// or like this if it return also minimum

return {
  max: {
    x: 269.52487694376975,
    y: 300
  },
  min: {
    x: 0
    y: 0
  }
}
```

> I have tried before, but with for loops, and isn't giving me any result at all. and a lot of code. (if possible a simple way)

thanks

Comment: Even if your attempt doesn't work, you should show your attempt to us, so we can either correct the attempt, or show you a solution and tell you why yours didn't work.

Comment: @caTS I tried `Math.max(array.x)` now and still not work

Comment: Because `array.x` is nothing.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski why? is nothing

Comment: Because you never declared it. Example: Every human has a right hand. Does a list of all humans have a right hand? I didn't see a list with a right hand in my life.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski thanks, I upvoted your answer, and I will accept it for sure :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array.prototype.map` and `Math.max`

```js
let array = [{
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0
  },
  {
    "x": 3.6417243968365076,
    "y": 10
  },
  {
    "x": 9.34437089784549,
    "y": 20
  },
  {
    "x": 0.7464057532722523,
    "y": 30
  },
  {
    "x": 10.254345841653576,
    "y": 40
  },
  {
    "x": 40.665266471734526,
    "y": 50
  },
  {
    "x": 13.605184580988041,
    "y": 60
  },
  {
    "x": 56.1970151503722,
    "y": 70
  },
  {
    "x": 46.30684270171864,
    "y": 80
  },
  {
    "x": 86.97417514998948,
    "y": 90
  },
  {
    "x": 19.086639005143002,
    "y": 100
  },
  {
    "x": 74.53073691009028,
    "y": 110
  },
  {
    "x": 80.51273650018987,
    "y": 120
  },
  {
    "x": 125.67651066602721,
    "y": 130
  },
  {
    "x": 94.92603682139705,
    "y": 140
  },
  {
    "x": 81.41258620429245,
    "y": 150
  },
  {
    "x": 128.79236053348222,
    "y": 160
  },
  {
    "x": 101.73294154449238,
    "y": 170
  },
  {
    "x": 176.92343490767377,
    "y": 180
  },
  {
    "x": 148.01122343809243,
    "y": 190
  },
  {
    "x": 13.666705559256798,
    "y": 200
  },
  {
    "x": 190.95447678085023,
    "y": 210
  },
  {
    "x": 186.02329838354444,
    "y": 220
  },
  {
    "x": 207.04643642736238,
    "y": 230
  },
  {
    "x": 75.3481702154557,
    "y": 240
  },
  {
    "x": 49.14228670472814,
    "y": 250
  },
  {
    "x": 203.65260758421869,
    "y": 260
  },
  {
    "x": 69.53501551989147,
    "y": 270
  },
  {
    "x": 269.52487694376975,
    "y": 280
  },
  {
    "x": 184.31351948105274,
    "y": 290
  },
  {
    "x": 19.72787138830958,
    "y": 300
  }
]

const max = {
  x: Math.max(...array.map(e => e.x)),
  y: Math.max(...array.map(e => e.y)),
}

console.log(max)
```

Comment: small typo on the max y => `y: Math.max(...array.map(e => e.y))`

Answer (score 1):

```js
let array = [{
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0
  },
  {
    "x": 3.6417243968365076,
    "y": 10
  },
  {
    "x": 9.34437089784549,
    "y": 20
  },
  {
    "x": 0.7464057532722523,
    "y": 30
  },
  {
    "x": 10.254345841653576,
    "y": 40
  },
  {
    "x": 40.665266471734526,
    "y": 50
  },
  {
    "x": 13.605184580988041,
    "y": 60
  },
  {
    "x": 56.1970151503722,
    "y": 70
  },
  {
    "x": 46.30684270171864,
    "y": 80
  },
  {
    "x": 86.97417514998948,
    "y": 90
  },
  {
    "x": 19.086639005143002,
    "y": 100
  },
  {
    "x": 74.53073691009028,
    "y": 110
  },
  {
    "x": 80.51273650018987,
    "y": 120
  },
  {
    "x": 125.67651066602721,
    "y": 130
  },
  {
    "x": 94.92603682139705,
    "y": 140
  },
  {
    "x": 81.41258620429245,
    "y": 150
  },
  {
    "x": 128.79236053348222,
    "y": 160
  },
  {
    "x": 101.73294154449238,
    "y": 170
  },
  {
    "x": 176.92343490767377,
    "y": 180
  },
  {
    "x": 148.01122343809243,
    "y": 190
  },
  {
    "x": 13.666705559256798,
    "y": 200
  },
  {
    "x": 190.95447678085023,
    "y": 210
  },
  {
    "x": 186.02329838354444,
    "y": 220
  },
  {
    "x": 207.04643642736238,
    "y": 230
  },
  {
    "x": 75.3481702154557,
    "y": 240
  },
  {
    "x": 49.14228670472814,
    "y": 250
  },
  {
    "x": 203.65260758421869,
    "y": 260
  },
  {
    "x": 69.53501551989147,
    "y": 270
  },
  {
    "x": 269.52487694376975,
    "y": 280
  },
  {
    "x": 184.31351948105274,
    "y": 290
  },
  {
    "x": 19.72787138830958,
    "y": 300
  }
]
console.log(Math.max(...array.map(elem => elem.x)))
console.log(Math.max(...array.map(elem => elem.y)))
console.log({
  x:Math.max(...array.map(elem => elem.x)),
  y:Math.max(...array.map(elem => elem.y))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This function returns max number and min from array

```
function sortThem(numbers) {

  let minNum = numbers[0]
  let maxNum = numbers[0]

  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (minNum > numbers[i]) {
      minNum = numbers[i]
    } else if (maxNum < numbers[i]) {
      maxNum = numbers[i]
    }
  }

  const minMax = [minNum, maxNum]
  return minMax

}
```

Then use it like this

```
const results = sortThem([2, 9, 10, 17, 45])

console.log(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and calculate everything in one pass/iteration.

```js
const array = [
  {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
  },
  {
    x: 3.6417243968365076,
    y: 10,
  },
  {
    x: 9.34437089784549,
    y: 20,
  },
];

const findMaxAndMin = data => {
  return data.reduce(
    (acc, cur) => {
      return {
        max: {
          x: Math.max(cur.x, acc.max.x),
          y: Math.max(cur.y, acc.max.y),
        },
        min: {
          x: Math.min(cur.x, acc.min.x),
          y: Math.min(cur.y, acc.min.y),
        },
      };
    },
    { max: { x: null, y: null }, min: { x: null, y: null } }
  );
};

console.log(findMaxAndMin(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer using Array.reduce.

```
// reduce loops on the array items and apply a callback function
const max = array.reduce(
  /**
   * callback function that is called for each element of the array from index 0 to index array.length-1
   * @param currentMax an object {x: number, y: number} containing the current maximum of x and y. It is initialized to the second argument of reduce
   * @param currentItem the current element of the loop
   * @returns the value of currentMax that will be used for the next step of the loop
   */
  (currentMax, currentItem) => {
    return {x: Math.max(currentMax.x, currentItem.x), y: Math.max(currentMax.y, currentItem.y)};
  }, array[0] /* initial maximum set to the first element of the array */);
console.log(max);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use the underlying snippet to get your desired result:

```
var NewReturnObject = {
        min: {
            x: Math.min(...array.map(o => o.x)),
            y: Math.min(...array.map(o => o.y))
        },
        max: {
            x: Math.max(...array.map(o => o.x)),
            y: Math.max(...array.map(o => o.y))
        }
    }

    console.log(NewReturnObject);
```

For further references you can refer to underlying links as well:
[Obtain smallest value from array in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934877/obtain-smallest-value-from-array-in-javascript)
and
[Finding the max value of an attribute in an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020796/finding-the-max-value-of-an-attribute-in-an-array-of-objects)